# Passing `skipna` argument to `agg`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, aggregate

I want to set `skipna=False` when I use the `agg` method on a DataFrame.

My DataFrame has many (dynamic) columns. I'm performing `groupby` and aggregating using `agg`, like

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2], "B": [np.nan, np.nan], "C": [0, 0]})

# the sum of B is 0.0
df.agg({"A": "sum", "B": "sum", "C": "max"})
```

When I'm aggregating a single column, or using a single aggregation function across the entire DataFrame, I can add `skipna=False` so that the `nan` values aren't skipped, i.e.
`df["B"].sum(skipna=False)` or `df.sum(skipna=False)`. This doesn't work for me because I'm doing a bunch of different functions (sum, avg, max).

How can I pass that `skipna` argument via the `agg` method?

Answer (score 3):

Personally I'd do:

```
out = pd.Series({'A': df['A'].sum(skipna=False), 
                 'B': df['B'].sum(skipna=False),
                 'C': df['C'].max()
                })
```

Also, `agg` with lambda would work as well:

```
df.agg({'A': lambda x: x.sum(skipna=False),
        'B': lambda x: x.sum(skipna=False),
        'C': 'max'})
```

Comment: I would define an alias, like `nasum = lambda x: x.sum(skipna=False)`, then use this in `agg` ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you have lot of columns to aggregate here is another approach:

```
d = {"A": "sum", "B": "sum", "C": "max"}
pd.Series({c: getattr(df[c], f)(skipna=False) for c, f in d.items()})
```

---

```
A    3.0
B    NaN
C    0.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Nice one @Shubham!